Deer skin seat for japa
It is recommended to do japa or tapas sitting on a deer's skin...
But  is it not cruel in sentiment to sit on a dead animal's leather skin for own peace of mind?

yes its sin if the animal had been killed for skin.. but if its natural causes then its okai.. that is very difficult to tell..

but for meditation its ideal for sanyasis its tiger skin

These deer are actually hunted by Kshatriyas and they are skinned by the Kshatriyas servants and then donated to the Tapasvis and the Brahmanas.
Kshatriyas have the right to hunt deer. The servants of the Kshatriyas must follow the kings order that is their duty. A Brahmana can accept anything from the Kshatriyas which has been acquired Dharmically in donation.
